# How to end an array of json data, and echo another value?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using `php` to return an array of data, with the command `json_encode()`. I want to also send some other data after I send this array. I'm using the `jquery` library. My `php` code is as follows:

```
<?php    

////  Query
$sql = "SELECT gtn FROM $table WHERE gid < 10";

//// Open connection 
$con = pg_connect("host=12.12.2.2 port=5434 dbname=spatial_data user=postgres password=****");  
if (!$con){echo 'error connecting'; die; }

//// Run query
$query = pg_query($con, $sql);
$arrayData = array(); // Store results from query in arrays

//// Parse results
while($r = pg_fetch_row($query)) {
    $arrayData[] = $r[0];
}
echo json_encode($arrayData);

//// Return metadata about calculation
//echo "$('#messages').html('Result returned for New York')";

//// close connection
pg_close($con);   

?>
```

This `php` is responding to a `jquery` post command:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "/php/array_test_v3.php",  
  data:{vertices: pointlist},  
  success: function(arrayData){  
    //console.log(arrayData[0])
    for(i=0;i<arrayData.length; i++){
      setGeoJson(arrayData[i]);
    }
  }, 
  dataType:'json'
});
```

This is a spatial database, and when I query the information, I also want to return some other values. For example, if the area is New York, I want to return an array of data and also the string `New York`. At the moment the line `echo "$('#messages').html('Result returned for New York')";` just appends to the array of information. Is there a way that I can escape from the array, or do I need to have a separate `post` function to get this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `echo json_encode($arrayData);`, just fetch the meta data and then do:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'data' => $arrayData,
    'meta' => $metaData
));
```

And then in JQuery:

```
  success: function(result){  
    for(i=0;i<result.data.length; i++){
      setGeoJson(result.data[i]);
    }
    // do something with result.meta
  },
```

Comment: Thanks @ori! I learned several new things from your answer that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using php.
make the array like this below

```
while($r = pg_fetch_row($query)) {
    $arrayData[] = array('gtn'=>$r[0],'someotherkey'=>'someothervalue','anotherkey'=>'anothevalue');
}

echo json_encode($arrayData);
```

now in jquery you can do this

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/array_test_v3.php",  
        data:{vertices: pointlist},  
         success: function(arrayData){  

            $.each(arrayData,function(index,value){
                  setGeoJson(value.gtn);
                  $('#messages').html(value.someotherkey);
               })

        }, 
    dataType:'json'
    });
```

like this you can append or do any thing you like..